# How to display recent posts by category name in WordPress using shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to show the recent posts by category name using shortcode like:

```
[recent-posts posts="10" category="thecategoryname"]
```

My code below display the recent posts but I don't know how to display them by category in shortcode in the format above.

```
function recent_posts_function($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts' => 1,
    ), $atts));

    $return_string = '<ul>';
    query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $return_string .= '</ul>';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'recent_posts_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Comment: Well, you're missing category from the shortcode array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for your shortcode attributes:

```
// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'category' => 'thecategoryname',
        'posts' => '10',
    ), $atts )
);
```

Additionally, you need to add category_name to your query and how many posts per page.

Example (from your code above - modified):

```
   query_posts(
     array(
     'orderby' => 'date', 
     'order' => 'DESC' , 
     'posts_per_page' => $posts,
     'category_name' => $category
     )
    );
```